# Unable to connect to datastax cassandra

Tags: spring-boot, cassandra, datastax

I am tring to connect to datastax cassandra database. And the version of cassandra is 5.0.1. Mine is a springboot application and below is my pom.xml. I am using dse jar connect to the Database. But when I start my application I am getting "All host(s) tried for query failed". Can anyobody help me resolving this issue.

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.sample.myproject</groupId>
<artifactId>sampleproject</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>productsFilterRules</name>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-cassandra</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
                <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.datastax.dse</groupId>
        <artifactId>dse-java-driver-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.1</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.5.201505241946</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>jacoco-initialize</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <rules>
                    <rule>
                        <element>CLASS</element>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>*Test</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </rule>
                </rules>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: This is a working example: https://www.tuturself.com/posts/view?menuId=3&postId=1121

Comment: If you're getting connection issues, the problem isn't going to be in your pom.xml.  It could be that your data center names don't match the ones in your replication factor.  It could be that you've got an IP address wrong, or maybe that Cassandra isn't even running on that IP.  But the pom.xml tells us none of that.  Can you connect and run the query from within cqlsh?  If so, then it's in your code.